# Get Parameters for Methods in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get the parameters for a Method MemberType when using Get-Member?

Example:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member -MemberType Method
```

What I need from this example is the parameters and parameter types of each member in the list.

The purpose of this is to get the members, parameters, and parameter types of a COM+ object I have to create documentation for. So an example can't be .net specific.

I will be piping the member and parameter info into a razor template to generate the appropriate html.

Edit:
A better example would be this...

```
$comObj = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$comObj | Get-Member -MemberType Method
```

In this example I need to get the parameter names (if there are any) for each method returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Get-Member` is meant more for exploring .NET types than PowerShell Commands. For a simple "view" of a command's parameters try this:

```
Get-Command Get-Process -Syntax
```

For details on the parameters try this:

```
Get-Command Get-Process | Select -Expand ParameterSets
```

If you're looking for more detail on a .NET type member's parameters then try this:

```
C:\PS> Get-Process | Get-Member -Name WaitForExit

   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
WaitForExit Method     bool WaitForExit(int milliseconds), void WaitForExit()
```

As for COM objects, that is likely to be a bit more hit or miss.  PowerShell doesn't always get type metadata for COM objects.  BTW I do get parameter info (the parameter types) for the COM object you list in your question:

```
C:\PS> $comObj = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
C:\PS> $comObj | gm QueryApplicationFile


   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{790c6e0b-9194-4cc9-9426-a48a63185696}

Name                 MemberType Definition
----                 ---------- ----------
QueryApplicationFile Method     void QueryApplicationFile (string, string, string, bool, bool, SAFEARRAY(Variant))
```

I'm afraid that is all the info PowerShell will give you in this case.

Comment: I updated my question to add a bit of clarity... I usually don't get it right in the initial post :)    In the above example, I'm trying to get the member definitions for the initialized COM object. Where I need to go from there is get the parameter types for each method.

Comment: Yes, I think you are completely right about getting the correct definition for the COM objects. Even when trying my example above, I only get the type names and no parameter names... probably has something to do with how COM interfaces work. Thanks for your help and quick responses!

Comment: Bummer, I guess I'll just have to construct the definitions myself or try parsing the parameters within the definition... although without the parameter names, it doesn't make much sense. Thanks for the help!